# Write JSON file as UTF-8 encoded

Tags: java, json, utf-8

I am writing a method that writes some JSON to a file, which works fine. However, although I have set the output to be UTF-8, [Oxygen](http://www.oxygenxml.com/download.html) fails to read a pound and euro sign.

Java code:

```
Path logFile = Paths.get(this.output_folder + "/" + file.getName().split("\\.")[0] + ".json");
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(logFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    File fileDir = new File("test.json");
    Writer out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileDir), "UTF8"));
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    writer.write(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(all_questions));
}
```

"all_questions" is an arraylist of Question objects, which is being printed as a formatted piece of JSON by an ObjectMapper.

Some sample JSON with the pound sign looks like this:

```
{
      "name" : "RegExRule",
      "field" : "Q039_4",
      "rules" : [ ],
      "fileName" : "s1rules_england_en.xml",
      "error" : null,
      "pattern_match" : {
        "$record.ApplicationData.SiteVisit.VisitContactDetails.ContactOther.PersonName.PersonGivenName" : "^[\\u0000-\\u005F\\u0061-\\u007B\\u007d-\\u007f£€]*$"
      }
}
```

However, that is displayed in notepad++. In Oxygen, it is displayed as follows:

```
"pattern_match" : {
        "$record.ApplicationData.SiteVisit.VisitContactDetails.ContactOther.PersonName.PersonGivenName" : "^[\\u0000-\\u005F\\u0061-\\u007B\\u007d-\\u007fÂ£â‚¬]*$"
 }
```

Comment: Is the encoding in Notepad++ set to "UTF-8" and displays correct?

Comment: Yes it is. I expect it isn't in oXygen, but I was hoping to tell any editor how to open the file from the file contents itself?

Comment: You should add an `Oxygen` tag to the question if it has nothing to do with  the json/file itself - Does Oxygen even support UTF-8?

Comment: I couldn't find the tag when I looked. I found "Oxygene"...

Comment: Is file without UTF8 BOM marker, try adding magic bytes 0xEF,0xBB,0xBF to the start and see how Oxygen read it. Notepad++ has UTF8 and UTF8WithoutBOM formats, Notepad always save UTF8withBOM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When constructing the `OutputStreamWriter` object, you need to use `"UTF-8"` as the charset name, not `"UTF8"`:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(..., "UTF-8")
```

Alternatively, use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8` instead:

```
new OutputStreamWriter(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Java does not generally support reading/writing BOMs, so if you want your JSON file to have a UTF-8 BOM then you will have to write one manually:

```
Writer out = ...;
out.write("\uFEFF");
out.write(... json content here ...);
```

FYI, `PrintWriter` can manage the `OutputStreamWriter` and `FileOutputStream` objects for you:

```
Writer out = new PrintWriter(fileDir, "UTF-8");
```

Or:

```
Writer out = new PrintWriter("test.json", "UTF-8");
```

Lastly, why are you creating a `BufferedWriter` using `Files.newBufferedWriter()` only to ignore it and create a secondary `BufferedWriter` manually?  Why not just use the `BufferedWriter` that you already have:

```
Path logFile = Paths.get(this.output_folder + "/" + file.getName().split("\\.")[0] + ".json");
try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(logFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
    writer.write("\uFEFF");
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    writer.write(mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(all_questions));
}
```

Comment: BOM marker bytes are UTF-8=EF,BB,BF  / UTF-16BigEndian=FEFF / UTF16LittleEndian=FFFE

Comment: Worked nicely thanks. I think my code has a mixture of attempts in it, sorry for the mess. Also, I tried both "UTF8" and "UTF-8" but not "UTF_8"!. Dohhhh.

Comment: @Whome: Yes, the **binary bytes** of the encoded BOM are `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` (UTF-8), `0xFE 0xFF` (UTF-16LE), and `0xFF 0xFE` (UTF-16BE), but the BOM itself is always Unicode codepoint U+FEFF, so that is the character you have to pass to `Writer.write()` so it gets encoded by the specified charset when written to the output stream (`'\uFEFF'` -> `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` for UTF-8).

Comment: @Jon: when specifying a charset by **name string**, you have to use `"UTF-8"`, there is no `"UTF8"` or `"UTF_8"` charset name. `UTF_8` is a static `Charset` field of the `StandardCharsets` class.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: After +10y of Java I did not know Writer IO can decide the final bom marker bytes written to underlying outputstream. I have always used FileOutputStream reference to write leading bom bytes. Doh.

Comment: @Whome: it has no concept of BOMs. Remember that Java strings/characters are just Unicode codepoints in UTF-16 encoding. The code is passing in a normal Java character for Unicode codepoint `U+FEFF ZERO WIDTH NON BREAKING SPACE (which is also used for BOMs) and letting the `Writer` encode it using its specified charset, like it does for any other input character/string. The `Writer` does not know that a BOM is being written. U+FEFF in UTF-8 is encoded as `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`. Call `writer.write('\uFEFF')` in the middle/end of the file and you will see the same bytes appear.